# Put request returns BadRequest. Get, delete and Post work with no errors

Tags: asp.net, rest, request, put

This is the page that makes the requests

```html
         var customStore = new DevExpress.data.CustomStore({
    load: function(loadOptions) {
        return $.getJSON('/erg/api/api/Caveats');
    },
    byKey: function(key) {
        return $.getJSON('http://webcrm/erg/api/api/Caveats' + "/" + encodeURIComponent(key));
    },
    insert: function(values) {
        return $.post('http://webcrm/erg/api/api/Caveats', values);
    },
    update: function(key, values) {
        return $.ajax({
             url: 'http://webcrm/erg/api/api/Caveats' + "/" + encodeURIComponent(key),
            method: "PUT",
   data: values
        });
    },
    remove: function(key) {
        return $.ajax({
            url: 'http://webcrm/erg/api/api/Caveats' + "/" + encodeURIComponent(key),
            method: "DELETE",
        });
    },
    key: "CaveatID"
});
```

Here is the controller

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Description;
using CRMApi.Models;

namespace CRMApi.Controllers
{
    public class CaveatsController : ApiController
    {
        private CaveatEntities db = new CaveatEntities();

        // GET: api/Caveats
        public IQueryable<Caveat> GetCaveats()
        {
            return db.Caveats;
        }

        // GET: api/Caveats/5
        [ResponseType(typeof(Caveat))]
        public IHttpActionResult GetCaveat(int id)
        {
            Caveat caveat = db.Caveats.Find(id);
            if (caveat == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return Ok(caveat);
        }

        // PUT: api/Caveats/5
        [ResponseType(typeof(void))]
        public IHttpActionResult PutCaveat(int id, Caveat caveat)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            if (id != caveat.CaveatID)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            db.Entry(caveat).State = EntityState.Modified;

            try
            {
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!CaveatExists(id))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
        }

        // POST: api/Caveats
        [ResponseType(typeof(Caveat))]
        public IHttpActionResult PostCaveat(Caveat caveat)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            db.Caveats.Add(caveat);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = caveat.CaveatID }, caveat);
        }

        // DELETE: api/Caveats/5
        [ResponseType(typeof(Caveat))]
        public IHttpActionResult DeleteCaveat(int id)
        {
            Caveat caveat = db.Caveats.Find(id);
            if (caveat == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            db.Caveats.Remove(caveat);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return Ok(caveat);
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        private bool CaveatExists(int id)
        {
            return db.Caveats.Count(e => e.CaveatID == id) > 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Only the put request fails and returns a 400 bad request error.  The others work well with a normal 200 succcess code

I have tried everything possible including using fiddler to analyse the error.  I can open the url in the broser and can see all my data formatted in ajax.

**This is the webconfig file**

```js
The wrbapi was generated using asp.net and is connecting to a sql database

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301879
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-CRMApi-20161123093835.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-CRMApi-20161123093835;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="CaveatEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Caveat.csdl|res://*/Models.Caveat.ssdl|res://*/Models.Caveat.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=192.168.16.228;initial catalog=ERGSERVER;persist security info=True;user id=sa;password=Red0ne?!123;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <add name="ERGSERVEREntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Controllers.SalesSupportExecutive.csdl|res://*/Controllers.SalesSupportExecutive.ssdl|res://*/Controllers.SalesSupportExecutive.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=192.168.16.228;initial catalog=ERGSERVER;persist security info=True;user id=sa;password=Red0ne?!123;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <add name="ERGSERVEREntities1" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.SalesSupportExecutiveModel.csdl|res://*/Models.SalesSupportExecutiveModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.SalesSupportExecutiveModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=192.168.16.228;initial catalog=ERGSERVER;persist security info=True;user id=sa;password=Red0ne?!123;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  <add name="BacksModel" connectionString="data source=192.168.16.228;initial catalog=ERGSERVER;persist security info=True;user id=sa;password=Red0ne?!123;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /></connectionStrings>
  <appSettings></appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
      <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" />
      <remove name="WebDAV" />
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Formatting" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
</configuration>
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have following configuration entries in your Asp.NET webapi project. You have to remove WebDAv and WebDAVModule to allow PUT and DELETE.

```
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="WebDAV" />
    </handlers>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
```

If it is still not working, then verify if PUT verb is allowed by going to Handler Mappings in your IIS Manager. Look for ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0, open it by double clicking it. Next Click on Request Restrictions button and on check the Verbs tab, add PUT if it is missing or select allow all verbs.

**Update:**

Modify your client side code for PUT invoke to this

```
update: function(key, values) {
        return $.ajax({
             url: 'http://webcrm/erg/api/api/Caveats/' + encodeURIComponent(key),
            type: 'PUT',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: values
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Vinod I have changed the web config file as suggested and also I have looked at the extensionlessUrlHandler and initially added PUT then I selected all verbs.  I did this on the default site though.  Its still gives me a bad request error.  Not sure why but thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: I have also added the webconfig file

Comment: Is your Delete method working? Is the problem just with PUT?

Comment: While debugging, do you know if the execution reaches PUT method. Can you put a break point and see if the execution reaches into PUT method?

Comment: At this point looks like the data that you are trying to pass may not be matching with the expected parameters for PutCaveat method. What does the json payload looks like for PUT method that you are sending from the client side? Can you provide full error message details that you get on client side?

Comment: Please see my update with changes to how you invoke PUT method and make sure the values json matches with the Caveat c# object.

Comment: jquery.min.js:4 PUT http://webcrm/erg/api/api/Caveats/3 400 (Bad Request)send @ jquery.min.js:4ajax @ jquery.min.js:4update @ devcaveat.asp:64_updateImpl @ dx.all.js:21(anonymous function) @ dx.all.js:9update @ dx.all.js:20(anonymous function) @ dx.all.js:48(anonymous function) @ dx.all.js:48i @ jquery.min.js:2add @ jquery.min.js:2n @ dx.all.js:48(anonymous function) @ dx.all.js:48each @ jquery.min.js:2_saveEditDataCore @ dx.all.js:48saveEditData @ dx.all.js:48(anonymous function) @ dx.all.js:48  

This is the error I get.  I have updates the update script

Comment: Can you post the json for what the values object looks like? And have you updated your PUT method based on my suggestion? Which version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: Yes I have updated the put method

{"CaveatID":3,"Caveat1":"Subject to being Non Hazardous under WM3"}

This is the json

Comment: "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js 

Current jquery version

Comment: Do you know if the execution reaches PutCaveat method in the WebApi? Are you able to debug and step thru the method? You are returning BadRequest in two cases, is the source of BadRequest one of those two if conditions you have?

Comment: Can you show what does the Caveat c# class looks like?